# Problem in typing implies and because sign

Tags: symbols

I have been trying to type an assignment article and when I tried typing implies and because symbol it gave me error, I use Rightarrow command for implies but what should I use for because, is there any package that has to be installed?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can consult the [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) to find out, which symbols are available.

Using `amssymb` you can try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    implies: \(\rightarrow\)

    because: \(\because\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be `\Rightarrow`. The package `amsmath` defines `\implies` as `\Longrightarrow` with some spacing and dots check.

Comment: WYSIWYM: Use `\implies`, not arrows if you really want to typeset implication.

Comment: I checked the error was adding a typo in package amsmath and \Rightarrow doesn't need a package to work. That's what I found out yesterday.